# Errors when executing tests in Tycho but not in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho, eclipse-pde

I have a set of test cases that use the Eclipse `WorkbenchPage` and a couple of other classes to perform a set of functions.

When I execute the test bundle in Eclipse, all the test results are green. But when I "clean install" the same package in the command prompt, the build fails and shows test failures in my test classes.

What could be the problem here? I tried debugging my code from Maven but it didn't help at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tycho and Eclipse differ in how they determine the test runtime:

In Eclipse, by default the entire target platform and all projects from the workspace are included in the test runtime.

In Tycho, only the test bundle/fragment and its transitive dependencies are part of the test runtime. If your test has implicit dependencies, e.g. on a bundle which provides some UI via an extension point, you need to explicitly configure these in Tycho.

With the following build configuration, you can for example include the feature `org.eclipse.rcp` and all its transitive dependencies into the test runtime:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
   <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
   <version>${tycho-version}</version>
   <configuration>
      <dependency-resolution>
         <extraRequirements>
            <requirement>
               <type>eclipse-feature</type>
               <id>org.eclipse.rcp</id>
               <versionRange>0.0.0</versionRange>
            </requirement>
         </extraRequirements>
      </dependency-resolution>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```